# Generating a string variable based on an existing string variable

Tags: stata, data-wrangling

I am trying in Stata to generate a variable called `region_code`, based on another existing variable `region`,

Essentially, I want something that looks as follows:
Country    region                    region_code

X     South Asia                     SA

Y     Latin America & Caribbean      LAC

And this is the code that I have tried:

```
generate region_codes  = .
replace  region_codes  = "SA" if region == "South Asia"
replace  region_codes  = "LAC" if region == "Latin America & Caribbean"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialise a string variable with an empty string `""` not `.` -- which is numeric missing. Otherwise you will get an error message `type mismatch`.